# How to implement a timer in a TCP: after each package sent or after whole message?

Tags: python, tcp, timer, network-programming

I'm implementing a TCP protocol in Python as an assignment. I don't know how to exactly implement a timer to it, should I be starting it after each package sent and store the segment + destination address or should I be storing it and after all packages have been sent I start the timer?

My first thought is to create a Timer class as follow:

```
class Timer:
    # Here I'll be passing the retransmit method as callback
    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self._callback = callback
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._timer = None
        
    
    def start():
        self.stop()
        self._timer = asyncio.get_event_loop().call_later(self._timeout, callback)
  
    def stop(self):
        if self._timer != None:
            self._timer.cancel()
```

My Connection class is:

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, server, id_connection, seq_no_sender):
        # ...

        self._buffer = []

        self._timer = None
        
        # ...
    def send(self, data=b''):
        """
        Used by the application layer to send data
        """

        if self._timer != None:
            self._timer.stop()

        while len(data) > 0:
            payload = data[:MSS]
            
            header = make_header(src_port, dest_port, self.seq_no, self.ack_no, FLAGS_ACK)
            segment = fix_checksum(header + payload, src_addr, dest_addr)

            self.server.network.send(segment, dest_addr)

            self._buffer.append((segment, dest_addr, self.seq_no))

            self.seq_no += len(payload)

            data = data[MSS:]
        
        self._timer = Timer(1, self._retransmit())

        pass
```

I want to be able to store the unacked data in a buffer and retransmit it if no ACK has been received

Comment: [RFC 6298 - Computing TCP's Retransmission Timer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6298)